# Generalized Pell's equation where $N$ is perfect square

Tags: number-theory, solution-verification, diophantine-equations, recursion, pell-type-equations

Are all solutions of the equation $x^2-4My^2=K^2$, multiples of $K$? I am considering $M$ not perfect square. Any tests in Python show be true, but...

My code:

```
for x in range (1,8000):
    for y in range (1,8000):
            if (x*x-20*y*y)==36:
                print(x,y)
```

Result: $
54, 12\\
966, 216$

All multiples of $6$.

Any can a example of solution coprime (except by factor 2) with K?

Comment: No, if $x^2-My^2=K$ then $$(x^2+My^2)^2-M(2xy)^2=K^2.$$

Comment: This amounts to looking at $(x+y\sqrt M)^2.$

Comment: But there is no solution to $u^2-20v^2=\pm6,$ so that won't work for this particular case. It does work for the general case.

Comment: Interesting, i look for solutions of x^2 - 5y^2 = 6 and not find...

Comment: Entonces if K have solution, K^2 have too. It help for study the problem

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1048216_

Answer (score 1):

For the case $M=5, K=6,$ all solutions have $x$ divisible by $6.$

Modulo $2,$ you'd get $x^2\equiv 0\pmod{2},$ so $x$ is even.

Modulo $3,$ you get $x^2+y^2\equiv 0\pmod 3.$ A little work shows that this implies $x$ must be divisible by $3.$

---

In fact, this shows that if $x^2-20y^2$ is divisible by $6$ then $x$ is divisible by $6.$ It really has nothing to do with the "square" in $6^2.$

---

If $x^2-4My^2$ is divisible by $2,$ then $x$ will be, of course.

Comment: It implies solution for x^2-20y^2=16, conform Thomas Andrews

Comment: Conform? @vandev

Comment: The .py, give me:

Comment: 6 1
14 3
36 8
94 21
246 55
644 144
1686 377
4414 987

[Program finished]

Comment: 6 and 1,      14 and 3,     94 and 21,   etc.       not  multiples of 4

Comment: I am trying to prove -4m^p * n^q  = x^2 (mod  y^2r) have solutions entonces x>y^r   (p, q, r odd primes). If the Pell equation solutions are multiples of K, it will be easy. Very thanks by help me @Thomas Andrews

Comment: I meant "according to" not conform, sorry (i use google translate)

Comment: @Will Jagy, yes not totally, but can to understand. I have studying the Jacobi Symbol too. But I don't know how to apply in this case...

Comment: The problem is how to make p mod q and q mod p appear

Comment: @vandev  I put a bunch of examples in a separate answer.

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1048216_

Comment: @individ It is possible to reduce any quadratic expression to a Pell equation. This shows the great importance of this equation for quadratic Diophantine equations. In my particular case, it would be interesting to know, for example, for which cases of K and M, the solutions are necessarily multiples of K, as in the case of K=6 and M=5. In this discussion it was possible to learn that this is not always the case, according to the examples provided.

Answer (score 0):

$$  21^2 - 20 \cdot 4^2 = 11^2  $$
$$  21^2 - 20 \cdot 2^2 = 19^2  $$
$$  61^2 - 20 \cdot 12^2 = 29^2  $$
$$  41^2 - 20 \cdot 6^2 = 31^2  $$
$$  49^2 - 20 \cdot 6^2 = 41^2  $$
$$  69^2 - 20 \cdot 8^2 = 59^2  $$
$$  101^2 - 20 \cdot 18^2 = 61^2  $$
$$  89^2 - 20 \cdot 12^2 = 71^2  $$
$$  81^2 - 20 \cdot 4^2 = 79^2  $$
$$  161^2 - 20 \cdot 30^2 = 89^2  $$
$$  141^2 - 20 \cdot 22^2 = 101^2  $$
$$  141^2 - 20 \cdot 20^2 = 109^2  $$

Comment: Nice! There are two things I'm still thinking about: 1) the solutions have K and x odd. 2) What if x^2 - m^p n^q = K has no solution (ie for small K, for very large K it doesn't matter). I know that Pell's equation doesn't always have a solution, however there are few criteria to say and there is no general criterion either.

Comment: I tested x^2-3^3 * 5^3 y^2 = K in WolframAlpha and it only seems to work when K is a perfect square, i.e. maybe the solution of the original equation requires that K^2 be a fourth power

Comment: x^2 - 1^3 * 7^3 y^2 = K have solutions if K is perfect square or the double of a perfect square

Comment: the same thing for x^2 - 1^3 * 7^5 y^2 = K